# Compare a DateTime object against another in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, datetime, compare

Okay, so I'm making an online text-based game, and I'm stuck right now with an on completion:

```
function....

    // I can't get this script to execute when I know the time has passed.

    $now = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $row_date = new DateTime($row["due_date"], new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    if ($row_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') <= $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) 
    {
        mysql_query(".....")VALUES ("....")or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM ......")or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else 
    {
        // The time has not come yet.
    }
```

This code is to be executed every 10 seconds with jQuery's setInterval.

Comment: The default timezone is UTC for new `DateTime` objects, isn't it? (So you don't have to pass a DateTimeZone object as well, but make sure.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DateTime` is compareable

```
if ($row_date <= new DateTime) { /* Do something */ }
```

Comment: ive have tried this method its not working..... do i have to format the data first like this $row_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') <= newDatetime?  ..... heres an example of the time thats being compared to the time now || 2011-12-09 16:23:01<- drop | | now-> 2011-12-10 00:33:06..... nothing is working!!!!

Comment: Nope, like I wrote: No `format()`: `$a = new DateTime('2011-12-09 16:23:01'); var_dump($a <= new DateTime);
/* bool(true) */`

Comment: +1 For the reminder of how awesome it was when I first realized I didn't need to use `format()` :)

Comment: Compareable? Is that the technical term? =) The PHP manual is very verbose and clear about the DateTime object IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into a unix timestamp. Perfect for whatever your needs are.
You can use timestamps to sort time easily, and figure out what event comes first.

```
$ts=strtotime($date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid converting to DateTime class and use `seconds since Epoch` value to do any date comparison. Your code would be like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$row_date = strtotime($row["due_date"]);
if ($row_date <= time()) { // The time has come
    mysql_query(".....") VALUES ("....") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ......") or die(mysql_error());
}
else {
    // The time has not come yet.
}
```